# How to set the Hyperlinked url to open in New Window using TextBox Properties of a RDLC Report?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

I'm new to the RDLC Report.

**Detail about RDLC Report:**

I'm having an RDLC Report which named as "CustomReport.rdlc". Which is integrated into an MVC Application? Consider that, this report parameters are, name, id, salary, and contact details. Each Column is bound with the textbox. My Current Requirement is, I have taken the address of each customer from the Database and stored it as "location" parameter. When binding value to the "location", it were stored as "string".

**My Requirement:**

If the user clicks on the "Contact Details" Column Value, the new window should open, which downloads the location of the person. ForEx: Google Map Services.

**My Implementation:**

In our Code, I have implemented the following code to enable the Hyperlink property for my report viewer.

```
        if (reportPath.Contains("CustomerReport.rdlc"))
        {
            viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
            viewer.HyperlinkTarget = "_blank";

        }
```

I have assigned the Go To URL Properties Value as "[Location]". Because I have taken the URL directly from the DB. For Example[Sample Link for the Location](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Rameswaram,+Tamil+Nadu+623526/@9.2867184,79.3028783,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3b01e3c4e61cf2b3:0xd667f9b98bbd63a1!8m2!3d9.2876254!4d79.3129291). Once I rendered the RDLC Report, If I click on any one of the Contact Details Row Value", **the Linked URL Open in the "same" page. This was the Issue**

**My Expectation is:**

If I Clicks the Row Value, the linked page or document should open in a new page.

I have tried out the below TextBox Expressions for the hyperlink URL to open in new window

**Try 1:**

```
1.  "javascript:void(window.open('https:\\www.google.com','_blank'))"

2.   Fields!location.Value ? rs:Command=Render &rc:LinkTarget=_blank

3.  "'" & Fields!location.Value & "'"

4.   " ' "+" ' "+Fields!location.Value + " ' "+" ' "

5.   char(34) & Fields!location.Value & char(34)

6.   '<a href="'+[location]+'" target="_blank"></a>'
```

**Try 2:**

I have written an ActionResult on the Controller. Which means I have assigned below URL to RDLC Parameter location as  [ **"https://localhost:56743/BaseController/DownloadFile?location=[location]"**]
Once the user clicks on the Contact row, the related controller action method will call. I have written the response back as to below code:

```
public ActionResult DownloadFile(string fileName, string filePath)
    {
        string docName = string.Empty;
        string path = string.Empty;
        string download = string.Empty;
        docName = fileName.Length > 0 ? fileName : null;
        path = filePath.Length > 0 ? filePath : null;
        string fileContentType = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(docName);
        var absolutePath = Server.MapPath("~" + path);
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath)) return RedirectToAction("FileNotFound", "HomeManagement");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            download = download + "<script>";
            download = download + "window.open('" + HttpContext.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/" + path + "')";
            download = download + "</script>";
        }
        return Content(download);
    }
```

After the Controller Action Call,
**As per My Expectation, the linked document is opened in a new window. But the RDLC Document is redirected to the "Hyperlinked URL" which shows as Empty in Preview**

**Try 3:**

I have written a **custom code in Visual Basic** inside the "Code" tab of RDLC Report Properties. And Called that code in the **"Go to URL"** textbox of ContactDetails Properties.

**RDLC Custom Code:**

```
Module OpenDocument
  public function GetUrl(byVal  FilePath as string) as string
    return ("'"+FilePath+"'")
  End function
End Module
```

**Called that custom code in the "Go To URL":**

```
 =Code.OpenDocument.GetUrl([Fields!location.Value])
```

But Above Tries not works.

**Expectation:**

**"Once we click on the Column Value, the hyperlinked document should download or the linked document should open in a new window?"**

Could anyone suggest me a better solution to overcome this issue?

Comment: You are creating serviceHub but then you start hub. Also the serviceHub on the server side calls the client's `addMessage` but you only have a handler for `broadcastMessage` on the client side.

Comment: I  don't need to send any data from client to server.that's why i just  temporarily created $.connection.hub.start().function(){}); .i need is only use  the  signalr for receiving.shall i remove the $.connection.hub.start() function from client.after remove hub start it works only for receiving data from server?

Comment: Hi folks! I couldn't able to ask a new question in a stack overflow. so that, I had modified the existing question.

Comment: this is not VBA, the Visual Basic code looks like VB.Net, please amend tag.

Answer (score 2):

I've already tried all the following options and can confirm they work:

- Option 1 - Set href attribute to a javascript which opens link in new window (RDL, RDLC, Report manager site)
- Option 2 - Set HyperlinkTarget="_blank" for Report Viewer control (RDL, RDLC, Report manager site)
- Option 3 - Pass rc:LinkTarget Html viewer command in Query string (Report manager site)

**Option 1 - Set href attribute to a javascript which opens link in new window**

It works for both RDL, RDLC reports and in Report manager site.

Assuming you have a `Name` field and a `Url` field in your report. Then open the `Placeholder Properties` window for `Name` field and for its `Value` set the following expression:

```
="<a href=""javascript:void(window.open('" & Fields!Url.Value & "'),'_blank')"">" & Fields!Name.Value & "</a>"
```

Also make sure you check `Html - Interpret HTML tags as styles` in `Markup type` section.

**Option 2 - Set HyperlinkTarget="_blank" for Report Viewer control**

It works for both RDL, RDLC reports and in Report manager site.

Using code or using designer, set `HyperlinkTarget="_blank"` for report viewer control:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" HyperlinkTarget="_blank" ProcessingMode="Remote">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/Test" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

This way, all the links will be opened in new window. So it's enough to make the `Name` field as hyperlink easily by opening `Placeholder properties` and then in the `Action`, set it to `Go to Url` and for url expression `=Fields!Url.Value`.

**Option 3 - Pass rc:LinkTarget Html viewer command in Query string**

It works for RDL in Report manager site.

You can add a query string parameter `rc:LinkTarget=_blank` which is a HTML Viewer Command. For example:

```
http://localhost/Reports/report/MyReport?rc:LinkTarget=_blank
```

This way, all the links will be opened in new window. So it's enough to make the `Name` field as hyperlink easily by opening `Placeholder properties` and then in the `Action`, set it to `Go to Url` and for url expression `=Fields!Url.Value`.

Comment: Hi @Reza, the above 3 Options not working in both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome Browsers.

Comment: @ThiruArasu I've already tried them all and I can confirm all are working (otherwise I hadn't posted them).

Comment: Between above options, option 2 is very straightforward.

Comment: Hi @Reza, I have tried out all three options. But, If I click on the hyperlink, the linked file opening on the same page. Not in the new tab. Once I set the hyperlink target into "_blank", that also not working.